# Self-hosted web app to create dynamic and 'pretty' file indexes from file hierarchies on the web server

Tags: file-management, nginx

I fairly often use the native nginx function to create indexes from a directory to share collections of files through the autoindex directive.

```
autoindex on;
```

[image: default file index on nginx]

This works but the index created is sometimes a little confusing for new users since parts of filenames may not be visible, it's not obvious which files are of which type, or whether they're files or directories.

**Is there an app that would make these indexes but prettier? They need to be dynamic because the file set changes.**

Preferably a python app since I have python env already set up but I won't be too picky. Pretty file icons and maybe even thumbnails would be nice. Like the autoindex, it would also need to stop at a given directory level so it doesn't serve the whole server content.

I've seen [fancy index](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/fancy_index/) but it looks unmaintained and cumbersome to install. Requires rebuilding nginx and won't be compatible with future updates, requiring rebuilding again.

There are also of course NextCloud and other large solutions but they're a little too involved and complicated for the purpose here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NGINX Extras by GetPageSpeed.
Fancyindex module is available as an [RPM package](https://nginx-extras.getpagespeed.com/modules/fancyindex/), thus none of this:

> cumbersome to install. Requires rebuilding nginx and won't be compatible with future updates, requiring rebuilding again.

Upgrades are as easy as just running `yum update`.

This, of course, assumes you're willing to have a paid subscription and running any of the operating systems supported (all are RPM-based).